# UITableViewCell editing style for specific rows

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been trying to delete particular rows in `UITableView`, using below delegate method

```
tableView commitEditingStyle:editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:
```

My intension is to not to show the "Delete" button for particular cells only.
please any one can help me how to solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use following Datasource method of `UITableView`

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the apply specified item to be editable.

    if("Your Condition") // such like indexPath.row == 1,... or whatever.
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

In short `return  YES` on specific **row/cell** which you want to edit otherwise `return NO;`